# How to test a client implementation against a broken server?

Tags: java, testing, client-server

I'm working on a Java HTTP client class that connects to external services (using Apache HttpComponents). I need to make sure that my client implementation keeps behaving in a predictable way when the server side starts working unexpectedly, in scenarios like abrupt disconnections, malformed responses, inconsistent headers, timeouts etc.

How can I reliably simulate such conditions when running a test? I don't mind connecting to a malfunctioning remote server, but a solution that works locally would be preferable.

Comment: couldn't you just use a mock object? Or in this case a mock server.

Answer (score 1):

1. you could use java Socket and ServerSocket class to mock server behavior, but i think it is too tedious to code.
2. you could use some mature framework like apache mina framework please refer http://mina.apache.org/
3. you could config apache http server to made your client access different virtue directory. the apache http server has the ability to response different http code according to your URL path.
4. you could install simple apache tomcat servlet container and write some JSP. within those JSP you could define response.setHeader or some other http response code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a simulator, which will simulate the behavior same as your server. Code it in such a way that it will send the above responses one by one for same request, so that you will be able to test all the response messages. You can also hardcode the responses in the simulator, if you know what responses could be sent by the actual server  for all those conditions.

Comment: This would be the safest choice I guess, though it would be a bit like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: but even hardcoded responses can do the job if needed only for testing

Comment: Sure, I just need test cases for situations that cannot be reproduced with a response

Answer (score 0):

Try Arquillian (http://arquillian.org/) framework. Probably suits your needs.

Here's features list: http://arquillian.org/features/